# How to create a news blogging system in JSP?

Tags: wordpress, jsp, tomcat, blogs

I'm looking for a news bloggin system (like Wordpress) that can be integrated in a Java website running on Tomcat server.
I know that Wordpress has some kind of API to receive XML data but I don't want to build from scratch the entire layout of the blog. Is there anything ready to use?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want blogging software implemented in Java, how about [Apache Roller](http://roller.apache.org/)? Writing your own blogging software from scratch may seem like fun, but you are more likely to create something with fewer features and more security holes.

If you are looking for an academic project to learn some techniques, go for it. If you just want to more easily integrate some blogging software into your existing Java stack, try Roller.

Comment: It's a nice example to start from.